# Sitecore 9.1 and Active Directory compatibility question

Tags: configuration, active-directory-module

I was looking into installing Sitecore 9.1 and was reviewing the modules compatibility table for XP (https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/541788) and was surprised to see no support for Active Directory modules. That would be a deal breaker for us. Did they replace it with something else to allow you to configure connectivity with Active Directory?
Please and thank you.

Comment: I reached out to Sitecore shortly after 9.1 was released and asked about just this very thing. At this time they have no production ready support for using Active Directory. There is something in the works but nothing published officially.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sitecore 9.1 uses an Identity server to handle logins instead of the old methods.

"With federated authentication now in widespread use across the industry, Sitecore finally provides user authentication and authorization through a centralized federation service. Built and run as a separate application, Identity replaces the traditional Sitecore login process, and provides federated authentication options and single-sign services in one portal." 
[9.1 sitecore updates](https://blogs.perficientdigital.com/2018/11/01/the-top-new-features-in-sitecore-9-1-and-why-they-matter/)
[Sitecore 9.1 Identity Server](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/91/sitecore-experience-management/en/sitecore-identity-server-authentication.html)

Comment: It would be good to potentially show how you would connect Active Directory to Sitecore 9.1 using Identity Server

Answer (score 1):

Sitecore Experience Platform 9.1.0 or later does not support the [Sitecore Active Directory module](https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Active_Directory/14/Active_Directory_14.aspx). You can use the Sitecore Identity server as a federation gateway to let users log in to Sitecore through an external provider. Below are the steps to integrate Azure Active Directory(AD) with the Sitecore identity server. This will enable the user to log in to Sitecore via organizations credentials using SSO.

**Azure AD set up**

- Go to the Azure portal and look for the Active Directory module and create a new tenant by providing the organization name and domain.
- Go to your directory and click on ‘App registration’ then click on ‘New Registration’. Give this app a name and select the tenant we have created and give Sitecore identity server URL (append `/signin-oidc`) in *‘Redirect URI’* field.

[image] [image]

- Note down the Client ID and tenant ID. You’ll need these when configuring Sitecore Identity.
- Go to the Manifest tab and edit `groupMembershipClaims` setting to `SecurityGroup`.
  [image]

**Setup Sitecore Identity**

- Navigate to the identity server instance and go to this path *\sitecore\Sitecore.Plugin.IdentityProvider.AzureAd\Config*.
- Open *Sitecore.Plugin.IdentityProvider.AzureAd.xml* for edit. You can change the display name. Give the values of client ID and Tenant ID which we noted down from Azure AD. Don’t forget to change Enabled to true.

[image]

- Restart the Sitecore identity server and try to login to CMS. You should see the below screen.

[image]

- Click on the Azure AD button and it will take you to the Microsoft sign-in (organization SSO) page. Since we did not map any user (who will be authorized to log in ), we will not be able to log in. To do that you'll need to map the AD users with Sitecore.

Reger to my blog to see this implementation in detail: https://sitecorewithraman.wordpress.com/2021/01/01/sitecore-cms-azure-ad-integration/